# Posting a nested collection from view to post controller using default model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-binding

I am building an asp.net mvc web application. I have the following set up so that my application can ask a person questions with multi-choice answers.

```
public class NewPerson
{
   public List <Question> Question {get; set;}
   // and other properties
 }

public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId{get; set;}
    public string QuestionText {get; set;}
    public List<Answer> Answers {get; set;} //list of multi-choice answers
}

public class Answer
{
     public int Answerid{get; set;}
     public string AnswerText {get; set;}             
 }
```

In my controller I have an instance of newPerson which is populated with questions and answers. This is then sent to the view.  I want my view to send this data back to the post controller.  I have tried to do this by using the default model binder.  I have attempted to use the method suggested by 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pmfawas/Asp-Net-mvc-how-to-post-a-collection/

In my razor view I have

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.NewPerson
```

The following code allows the model binder to bind the properties QuestionId and QuestionText

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Questions[i].QuestionId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Questions[i].QuestionText)
    }
```

I would like to do something similar for Answer List but I can't see a way to do it.  Any help on how to do this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're gonna need a nested for Loop to access `Questions[i].Answers[m]`

```
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count(); i++)
   {
      @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Questions[i].QuestionText)    

       for (int m = 0; m < Model.Question[i].Answers.Count(); m++)
       {
          @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Questions[i].Answers[m].AnswerText)
       }
   }
```

If anyone has questions about how to populate the model do it like this

```
NewPerson model = new NewPerson();

model.Questions = (insert LinQ Query).ToList();

foreach(var item in model.Questions)
{
   item.Answers = (insert LinQ Query).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Although presumably you mean m < Model.listModel.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Yea I tested this with my Objects, so you might see a typo I think I corrected all of it now